# How to Change Controller Name and function name URL in Grails 2.2.2?

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I am trying to change my controller name and method name in grails

**e.g :abc.com/newUser/viewUser/4**

i want to convert in below format 
**e.g :abc.com/new-user/view-user/4**

Or

**e.g :abc.com/new_user/view_user/4**

for that i wrote a code :

```
package customize

import grails.web.UrlConverter

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

class CustomUrlConverter implements UrlConverter {

    private static final String GRAILS_EXTENSION = '_'

    String toUrlElement(String propertyOrClassName) {

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(propertyOrClassName)) {

            return propertyOrClassName

        } else {

            String[] r =    propertyOrClassName.split("(?=\\p{Upper})");
            String lowerPropertyOrClassName = propertyOrClassName.toLowerCase();
            println r.length + "size()";
            String extendedPropertyOrClassName="";
            if(r.length > 1){
                for(int i=0; i < r.length;i++){
                    extendedPropertyOrClassName = extendedPropertyOrClassName + r[i].toLowerCase()
                    if(i+1 <  r.length ){
                    extendedPropertyOrClassName =addGrailsExtension(extendedPropertyOrClassName);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                extendedPropertyOrClassName =  propertyOrClassName.toLowerCase()
            }
            return extendedPropertyOrClassName

        }
    }



    private String addGrailsExtension(String propertyOrClassName) {

        if (propertyOrClassName.endsWith(GRAILS_EXTENSION)) {

            return propertyOrClassName

        } else {

            return propertyOrClassName + GRAILS_EXTENSION

        }

    }
}
```

In Config.groovy

```
grails.web.url.converter = 'hyphenated'
```

// grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy

```
beans = {
    "${grails.web.UrlConverter.BEAN_NAME}"(com.myapplication.MyUrlConverterImpl)
}
```

In this when i am trying to get all character in small letter like below Url

**e.g :abc.com/newuser/viewuser/4**

its working fine

But when i add underscore in between two character like below Url

**e.g :abc.com/new_user/view_user/4**

Its gives an error 404..
Please Help me out. If you have any other option to change URL also welcome..

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easiest way to achieve your requirement is `UrlMappings.groovy`

```
"/new_user/view_user/$id"(controller: 'newUser', action: 'viewUser')
```

Comment: "/new_user/view_user?/$id?(.${format})?" - Why do you want the question mark behind `view_user`, or is that a typo?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown - I have taken this syntax from http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Plug-ins/URL%20mappings.html, `?` after action name. I have also tried without `?` and it works. Which is the recommended way? Please suggest.

Comment: "I have taken this syntax from grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Plug-ins/URL%20mappings.html, ? after action name". - You have not used the question mark after an action name.  You have used the question mark behind a string literal in your mapping. I am not sure what effect you think the question mark has in the context in which you have used it, but I don't think there is any reason to include a question mark there. The question mark is only useful behind variable names in the mapping.

Comment: I am also not sure that the `id` should have a question mark behind it for this particular type of mapping.  It doesn't make sense to request to view a user and not supply an id.  Since this mapping is specifically for viewing a user, it probably makes more sense to have the id be required, not optional.  The question mark makes it optional.

Comment: Why wouldn't "/new_user/view_user/$id(.${format})?"(controller: 'newUser', action: 'viewUser') or "/new_user/view_user/$id"(controller: 'newUser', action: 'viewUser') (depending on the requirements) make more sense?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown - Thanks for replying and provide this valuable information. Will Update my answer.

Comment: fwiw... I think it is irresponsible to answer people's questions using code samples that you don't understand.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown - Yes you are right. I am sorry for this. But if I was not share then I was not got this valuable information. I am learning from other answer and from my mistakes.

Comment: how to map e.g abc.com/newuser/viewuser/4?index=1 this kind of url ??? @user1690588

Comment: @SAGARMANE - Try to add `?` after id, like `/new_user/view_user/$id(.${format})?`

Comment: @user1690588 : solved.. /new_user/view_user/$id/${format}? with this format

Comment: @user1690588 : how to do with method "post"

Comment: @SAGARMANE - Have a look: http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#urlmappings